# How to set IN operand using setString() in HQL query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

We can set id if sql is like

```
select * from user where id = :id
```

using `setString("id", "0")`

How can I set id when it is like

```
select * from user where id in (0,2)
```

in HQL query.

Comment: You can't generalize like that and the leave it up to the people you are asking for help to figure it all out. You don't want to do it "in Java", apparently you are asking how to do it through the Hibernate API if I have to believe your tag. So I'm also guessing you want to do it in a HQL query and not in an SQL query / prepared statement.

Comment: Ok, I will edit my question. You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way:

Get preparedStatement by passing sql query string as "select * from user where id in (?,?)" and then set the values for id as:

```
    stmt.setInt(0);
    stmt.setInt(2);
```

where stmt is an instance of [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

**EDIT for HQL:**

With HQL you can query it as:

```
    Query q = session.createQuery("from user u where id IN (:ids)");
    q.setParameterList("ids", idList);
```

where idList is List of ids you want to pass.